# cant connect sqlite query with php page

Tags: css, image, background

I have a sqlite database connected to a booking system. I want to run a query so that when i click a button on my reports.php page the query will display the number of bookings in the database between two dates. Im quite new to php and this is my first major project. Here is my code.

```
$db = new SQLiteDatabase('daypilot.db');
//connection code here
$result = $db->query("SELECT Count FROM events where start between '2018-02-09' and '2018-02-20'"); //replace exec with query
```

Comment: What does the code you posted have to do with CSS and background images?

Comment: My apologies that was from a post i didnt submit that i was typing previously